# Are the webserver code names auto generated by shotgun (sinatra)?

Tags: sinatra, shotgun

I just learned about sinatra and shotgun. When I run shotgun, I see `Thin web server (v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)` I saw another codename just now (`Gob Bluth`)

Are these codenames auto generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shotgun is a reloader for Sinatra. An application that uses Sinatra can be run on it's own without Shotgun. Shotgun makes development easy since you don't have to restart the server every time you change a piece of application code.

The server code names are generated by the underlying Rack handler. For instance, [this is what](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/d2da2caf49932827f07994c8b65b1f99001c5fb9/lib/puma/const.rb#L103-L105) Puma does when the server starts. The codename in the case of Puma depends on the handler version, and not the running instance. In your case, Thin [1.6.4 is codenamed "Gob Bluth"](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/d0aef2e80216701b48b908dc14befe3600a44346/lib/thin/version.rb)

Comment: "Shotgun is a reloader for Sinatra"-- finally cleared (for me) the relationship btw Shotgun and Sinatra. I struggled to figure out how to ask that question. So t.y.

Comment: Yes, you can use Sinatra without Shotgun :)